# Java: How do I know which container a component sits on

Tags: java, swing

The title is a bit ambiguous and I will explain in codes. Suppose I have

```
Class A extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
     B b;
     Class B extends JPanel{
         public JButton button;
         public B(A a){
               button = new JButton();
               button.addActionListener(a);// I want to process all actionEvents in A
               this.add(button);
         }
     }
     public A(){
         b = new B(this);
         //irrelevant codes omitted for brevity  
     }

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
         //Here's the question: 
         //Suppose I have a lot of Bs in A, 
         //how can I determine which B the button 
         //that triggers this callback belongs to?
     }
}
```

So is there any way to to that? Or my idea is wrong? Any thought is welcomed.

EDIT:
What I finally do is to add a function `has(JComponent component)` to B to compare against every clickable B has. The `getParent()` becomes awkward when you have multiple layers of JPanel as it's hard to figure out which layer of panel it's referring to and it's against the idea of encapsulation.

Comment: Do you mean which class an object belongs to?

Comment: @NazarMerza I care more about which instance an object belongs to as I can have a bunch of instances from the same class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `e.getSource()` to get a reference to the exact component that triggered the event. In your case, it will be a `JButton`. To get the panel it sits on, use `e.getSource().getParent()`.

Comment: But will the `e.getSource()` return the button or an instance of b? If I get a reference to button, how can I trace back to THAT instance of b?

Comment: `e.getSource().getParent()` will give you the panel the button sits on.

Comment: @flup THat's the answer I want to see. Thanks!

Comment: @flup, can you please phrase this as an answer so the OP can accept it? I'll delete mine afterwards.

Comment: Have edited this answer to add the getParent(). Nvm the points :)

Comment: (I'd like to see you cast the ActionEvent#getSource result to at least a JComponent, but otherwise +1)

Answer (score 1):

Say you have `B[] bs = new B[n];`

Then you could set `action command` for each button, such as:

```
for (B b : bs) {
    b.setActionCommand("some identifiable command");    // use different command for different buttons
}
```

Then in the `actionPerformed` method, switch on the commands:

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    switch (e.getActionCommand()) {
        case "cmd1":
            // do something
            break;
        case "cmd2":
            // do something
            break;
        default:
    }
}
```

You can also use `Action` objects, which is more flexible but a little more complicated.
For more information, please read Java tutorial:

- [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)
- [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)